# traffic tracking WinRT UWP windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, windows-runtime

trying to receive data about received and sent bytes in every connection, that createt at the PC. I'm using WinRT UWP windows 10app, namespace Windows.Networking.Connectivity.
Here is my metode

```
private ulong BytesReceivedCheck(ConnectionProfile connectionProfile)
        {
            var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
            //Get the ConnectionProfile that is currently used to connect to the Internet
            IAsyncOperation<IReadOnlyList<NetworkUsage>> LocalUsage = connectionProfile.GetNetworkUsageAsync(startDate, currentDate, DataUsageGranularity.Total, new NetworkUsageStates());
            var networkUsages = LocalUsage.GetResults();
            foreach (NetworkUsage networkUsage in networkUsages)
            {
                return networkUsage.BytesReceived;
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

I'm giving this metode as a parameter to a object

```
ConnectionModel model = new ConnectionModel(BytesReceivedCheck(connectionProfile));
```

Here is my model

```
public class ConnectionModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
ulong bytesReceived;
public ulong BytesReceived
        {
            get
            {
                return this.bytesReceived;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this.bytesReceived != value)
                {
                    this.bytesReceived = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
public ConnectionModel(ulong bytesReceived)
        {
            this.BytesReceived = bytesReceived;
}
}
```

I'm receiving exceprion "method invoked in unexpected time" in line `var networkUsages = LocalUsage.GetResults();` in my methode. I think problem with Async, pls give me correct example of this method. I'm a begginer so sorry for maybe dumb question.

Comment: Use the `await` keyword to wait for the results to be ready.